# Trigger to update table column when data is inserted in another table from a different database

Tags: sql, database-trigger

I have a database table named `vendor_invoice` which contains columns `invoiceNo` and `paymentref` in database Interface. I want to update the `paymentref` column once data has been inserted into another database table named `APTCR` which is located in another database, `JBDAT`. Note that table `APTCR` has both the `paymentref` and `invoiceno` columns.

Comment: What database server software are you using? Are both databases located in the same server instance? Note that cross-database operations are generally a bad idea as it reduces your application's portability.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible if you use like oracle dblink or db2 federation or change data capture software.

If you use dblink or federation. You can use trigger :

```
create or replace trigger aaa
begin
...
end;
```

Otherwise, IBM IDR, Oracle Data Replication would be a good solution